# Recycler's content doubles every time the fragment is added to the fragment manager even though it should be cleared

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have an fragment with photos recycler (user profile with a gallery).

I populate the recycler in `onViewCreated`, and my function calls `adapter.clear()` before listening to the data. I try to clear twice actually.
I add the fragment to the supportFragmentManager, and when the back button is clicked I pop the back stack.

The problem is, that even though I pop the stack (which as to my understanding, should remove the fragment and completely destroy it), when I re-add the fragment and go to the profile of the same user, the gallery now has double the photos. If I do it again, it will be triple.

This is my function:

```
private fun listenToImagesFromRoll() {

    galleryRollAdapter.clear()

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/${userProfile.uid}/images")

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            for (imagePath in p0.children){


                val imageObjectPath =
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/images/${imagePath.key}/body")

                imageObjectPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        val imageObject = p0.getValue(Images::class.java)
                        if (imageObject != null) {

                            imageList.add(FeedImage(imageObject, 1))
                            galleryRollAdapter.clear()
                            galleryRollAdapter.addAll(imageList.reversed())
                        }
                    }
                })

            }

        }


        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
}
```

I call this inside in the in create method, inside an `Observer` that holds the user which profile I open.

This is how I add the fragment:

```
activity.subFm.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.feed_subcontents_frame_container, activity.profileSecondRandomUserFragment, "profileSecondRandomUserFragment").addToBackStack("profileSecondRandomUserFragment")
.commit()
```

And this is how I pop it:

```
subFm.popBackStack("profileSecondRandomUserFragment", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

Can't understand why it keeps re adding the photos.

Comment: I think you need to clear the collection within the adapter and add them again. After that use notifyDataSetChanged to taking effect. It may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your list before every time you want to load fresh new content.

or it will just append a new set of data at the end of your list.

```
           imageObjectPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    val imageObject = p0.getValue(Images::class.java)
                    if (imageObject != null) {
---- The point is to clear the collection
---- before you tell your adapter to update the list, like this
                      ++imageList.clear()
                        imageList.add(FeedImage(imageObject, 1))
                      +-galleryRollAdapter.clear()// may not need, try it
                      +-galleryRollAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            })
```